# Passing special characters via apache HTTPClient

Tags: character-encoding

I have a servlet which accepts HTML content as part of the request param. The HTML is a localized one which may be a french, spanish etc... content. 
I'm also using apache HTTP client to make a request to this servlet for test purpose, which has the following header definition:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

PostMethod method = new PostMethod("<URL>");
String html = FileUtils.readFileToString(inputHTMLFile, "UTF-8");
method.addParameter("html", html);

method.addRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");    
method.setRequestHeader("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
```

Whatever HTML is read has the character encoding utf-8, sample text:

```
Télécharger un fichier
```

However when i get the html from the request param that texts becomes `T?l?charger un fichier`

I went through few links such as http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/httpcharset-142283.html which talks about charset and how normally a browser would encode the special characters. If i were to URLEncode the html with UTF-8 and then decode that with same charset in the servlet i get the HTML as expected.

Is this the only thing i can do to preserve the charsets? Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that `html` is correct right after you decoded it from the file? You will probably see `�` when you `System.out.println(html)` That means the html file is not UTF-8. The presence of character x does not mean the file is in encoding y. The file can be in any encoding that supports the character x.

Comment: i'm now getting it correct for the french and spanish. i had change the encoding to utf-8 in notepad++. In the servlet after fetching the html i write back to a file using FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("c:\\test.html"),message, "UTF-8"); and i can see the chars propely. But for chinese even though i see the chars properly in my console after reading from file, during write it gets converted into ????

Answer (score 6):

Now that the issue with the file itself is fixed, try modifying your code as follows:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("<URL>");
 postMethod.getParams().setContentCharset("utf-8"); //The line I added

 ...
```

Note that the client needs to decode the request as UTF-8 now. French and Spanish worked correctly because their characters are included in the default ISO-8859-1 charset. Chinese characters are not. If the French and Spanish were decoded correctly on client, the client is decoding the request as ISO-8859-1, and sending UTF-8 could fail.

So you could try also adding this:

```
postMethod.setRequestheader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Strangely the html being passed is not coming in the request params, i tried doing the following: method.addParameter("html", html); as well as method.getParams().setParameter("html", html); the param comes as null, not sure why

Answer (score 4):

Just try this for post method.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(webServiceUrl);
StringEntity str = new StringEntity(YourData);
str.setContentType("application/json");
HttpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(str, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just for info Http.UTF_8 is deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128120/why-is-the-constant-http-utf-8-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You should better change string to base64 encoded and then send.

Comment: Can you provide some code for your answer? Maybe just one-liner?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the cause by examining EntityBuilder decompiled code: the EntityBuilder ignores the contentEncoding field regarding the parameters, it uses the one from contentType field. And by looking on org.apache.http.entity.ContentType the only one predefined value having UTF-8 is org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.

So in my case

```
HttpPost method = new HttPost("<URL>");
EntityBuilder builder = EntityBuilder.create();
builder.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.setContentEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
...
method.setEntity(builder.build());
```

did the job (although I think setting contentType is redundant here).

I'm using httpclient-osgi version 4.5.4.

Answer (score -1):

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod("URL");
method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```