# Why is the constant HTTP.UTF_8 deprecated?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

After upgrading to Apache HttpClient >=4.2, I found the following constant now deprecated:

```
org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP.UTF_8
```

Why was this constant deprecated (along with others) and what is the Apache HttpClient recommended alternative?  The [a HttpCore javadoc here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HTTP.html#UTF_8) lists it as deprecated but does not recommend an alternative.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since Java 7, Java provides the [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class for getting the `Charset` object for a few standard character sets. These are: ASCII, ISO-8859-1, [UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8), UTF-16, UTF-16BE, and UTF-16LE. That's the alternative.

There's no longer a point in re-declaring the `String` name of the character set in an `HTTP` class.

Comment: Thanks for this!

TL;DR HTTP.UTF_8 should be StandardCharsets.UTF_8 going forward.